# sockjs-node path is overwritten with webpack-dev-server baseUrl

Tags: docker, nginx, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, sockjs

**nginx.conf (exposed on port 8900 in docker-compose)**

```
upstream app_api {
    server api:8888;
}
upstream app_dashboard {
    server dashboard:8080;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name api_server;
    index index.html;

    # Needed for Django API testing
    location /static {
        alias /var/www/static;
        try_files $uri /$uri /index.html;
    }

    #Django API
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://app_api/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    # Dashboard static served from nginx
    location / {
        root /var/www/dist/;
        try_files $uri /$uri /index.html;
    }

    # Dashboard served from webpack-dev-server in container
    location /serve {
        proxy_pass http://app_dashboard;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    # still testing - this will fix the HMR for webpack
    location /serve/sockjs-node {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://app_dashboard;

        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

}
```

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'docker' ? '/serve' : '/'
}
```

In a browser go to:

> localhost:8900/serve

Pages get served fine, however,webpack-dev-server HMR is not working  since the calls to sockjs are now `/serve` instead of `/serve/sockjs-node` :

> POST http://localhost:8900/serve/908/3so2cyjm/xhr_streaming?t=1548885104223 404 (Not Found)

I am assuming this can be fixed with setting **devServer.proxy** instead of baseUrl, however I could not find the correct configuration.

What I need is:
`/` -> should go to `http://localhost:8900/serve`

`/api` -> should go to `http://localhost:8900/api`

`/sockjs-node` -> should go to `http://localhost:8900/serve/sockjs-node`

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I've got the same problem

Answer (score 2):

We can change the default socket path using sockPath option:

```
module.exports = {
    //...
        devServer: {
        sockPath: 'path/to/socket',
    }
};
```

Here will be:

```
sockPath: '/serve/sockjs-node',
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix that issue with something like:

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        "/serve": {
            target: "http://localhost:8900",
            pathRewrite: { "^/serve": "/sockjs-node" },
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! But don't you won't that route all requests to serve to sockjs? I only want websocket connection to route to /sockjs-node, and /api requests to go to /api.

I believe your solution is setting me on the right path, I will give it a try.